# How to use GDB to debug dependency files?

Tags: c, makefile, gdb

I wish to use gdb to debug a program. When I use `b lib.c:FUNCTION` to set a breakpoint in `lib.c`, GDB ignores the breakpoint:

```
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048d03: file lib.c, line 120.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/jharvard/Dropbox/project/macro_main 
usage: output file in rows of INT, INT, A or D
i.e. ./macro_main in/data_1
[Inferior 1 (process 14766) exited with code 01]
```

I think there may be something wrong with the Makefile. How can I fix it?

```
CC?=gcc
CFLAGS+= -g -Wall
LDFLAGS=
LIBS = -lm

macro_main: macro_main.o lsm.o lib.o level.o 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $^

clean:
    rm -rf *.o macro_main
```

Edit: below is what I get. The suspicious note is `Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y`. It seems to indicate something is not linked correctly in the Makefile.

```
me (~/Dropbox/project): make
make: Warning: File `Makefile' has modification time 1.7e+06 s in the future
clang -Wall   -c -o macro_main.o macro_main.c
clang -Wall   -c -o lsm.o lsm.c
clang -Wall   -c -o lib.o lib.c
clang -Wall   -c -o level.o level.c
gcc -o macro_main macro_main.o lsm.o lib.o level.o -lm
make: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
me (~/Dropbox/project): gdb ./macro_main in/data_1
Reading symbols from ./macro_main...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
"/home/me/Dropbox/project/in/data_1" is not a core dump: File format not recognized
(gdb) b main 
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048685
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/me/Dropbox/project/macro_main 

Breakpoint 1, 0x08048685 in main ()
(gdb) b lib.c:lsm_merge
No source file named lib.c.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y

Breakpoint 2 (lib.c:lsm_merge) pending.

(gdb) continue
Continuing.
usage: output file in rows of INT, INT, A or D
i.e. ./macro_main in/data_1
[Inferior 1 (process 16156) exited with code 01]
```

Comment: Are you sure the program ever calls that function?

Comment: How would gdb need dependency files? That would cause trouble with build tools like Scons which don't even need them.

Comment: Yes, when I run `./macro_main in/data_1`, it runs the content of `printf` in the function.

Comment: Perhaps the compiler's optimizer simply inlined the function, so it is never actually called?

Comment: Set a breakpoint where your code calls the function then single-step.

Comment: Are you sure it's putting the breakpoint in the _right_ `lib.c` file? I seem to have a vague memory of time where I tried setting a breakpoint in `main.cpp`, and it wasn't firing, and I think I eventually found out it was setting the bp in a different `main.cpp` from what I intended... ? Can't quite remember though.

Comment: Make sure you include `${CFLAGS}` (or, at least, the `-g` option) in the link line.  As it stands, you don't link with debugging, which makes it hard for GDB to debug the non-debuggable binary.

Comment: I added more information. GDB asks `Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y`, indicating some linking is not done. Sorry if the information I provided is not clear.

Comment: The `-g` option isn't being used anywhere, none of your object files are getting built with debugging information. That "Makefile has modification time in the future" also makes me nervous. The `make` system uses timestamps to decide what needs to be built. Doesn't look like it's causing you trouble here, but I've infinitely looped with `make` before because my system time was 3-4 years behind the real date. I think it would be prudent to make sure your system time is correct.

Comment: This output looks quite odd to me. Looks like you're setting gcc as your compiler, but then clang makes an appearance, and it also looks like you're adding `-g` to your `CFLAGS` but that option is nowhere to be found in the output. Are you sure you're running the right makefile? Use `make -f` to specify a file name if your make file isn't called "Makefile". You can also run make with the `-d` option to print its debugging information. You can run make with the `-n` option to do a dry run (doesn't actually execute the commands, just prints out what they are).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, below is working for me:

```
CFLAGS = -std=c99 -Wall -g -ggdb -O0
LIBS = -lm

macro_main: macro_main.o lsm.o lib.o level.o 
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -o  $@ $^ $(LIBS)


macro_main.o: macro_main.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -c macro_main.c

lsm.o: lsm.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -c lsm.c

lib.o: lib.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -c lib.c

level.o: level.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -c level.c

clean:
    rm -rf *.o macro_main
```